# How to quickly and inexpensively deposit cash?

Tags: united-states, cash

I placed in a poker tournament at a casino the other day. I went to my bank, Charles Schwab, to deposit the cash. They said "We don't accept cash deposits." I found this very odd given they're a bank, but I'm sure they have their reasons. They told me to go and get a money order from a nearby convenience store, but that would cost me $1-$2 per pop with a maximum of $500 per money order. Surely there has got to be a better way to get cash into a bank account? What's a recommended way that will charge me as little as possible to convert cash into digital funds?

Comment: How much cash are we talking about?  I've had no problems with cash deposits of several thousand dollars, but I expect that several hundred thousand might raise a few eyebrows :-)

Comment: Is the cash amount greater than $10,000?  If it is, then money laundering legislation requires that the bank file a report to the relevant authority, including the name of the person conducting the transaction and records of their financial transactions.  Maybe the bank doesn't want to carry the cost of the extra administration.

Comment: Are you sure that you went to a Charles Schwab _Bank_ branch?  I believe that there is only one (although it is in Nevada and so must be close to some casinos ...).  Officially, the other Schwab locations represent the brokerage side of the business, not the banking side.

Comment: Was there really no alternative to the casino giving you your prize in cash?

Comment: Be advised that in the US, poker winnings is income. Make sure you slap 30% of that win away if the casino didn't do that for you.

Comment: @corsiKa How would the taxable portion of those winnings be the responsibility of the casino? I'm not giving a casino my SSN.

Comment: about 3k. not sure about the Charles Schwab, and I'm aware of the taxes, just looking to use the dough

Comment: My bank has never made a problem about cash deposits. Is this a USA thing? Here we even have machines doing the work of the teller for them, giving you a receipt and all. I suspect it has more to do with the size of the deposit indeed, please clarify.

Comment: @Logarr Some casinos do it for everyone if you take them up on it. They are required to if you are from out of country, in fact. But you're missing the forest for the trees on my comment. The point of the comment was that at some point, Uncle Sam is gonna want his 30% so it makes sense to put that away while you can.

Comment: @Mast No, this is not a USA thing.  I've never had, or even heard of, a saying they don't take cash deposits.  I think OP is confused.

Comment: @corsiKa not quite.  It's only income if you are classified as a professional gambler, at which point you can deduct gambling losses and so forth using a schedule C.  If gambling isn't your day job then it's taxed at a flat rate, separate from your ordinary income.

Comment: @Logarr if you win a large slot jackpot or a large amount in a poker tournament, you absolutely are filling out tax forms or you are going home empty handed.  It's the responsibility of the casino because that is the law.

Comment: @eps No, it has nothing to do if whether you are a professional or not, it has everything to do with the amount that you win. Typically, only professionals break those thresholds.

Comment: @corsiKa I'm not sure what you mean by put it away. Let's say it is 3k like I said above, then 30% is $900. I could use that $900 now, say, invest it, or pay bills, and the $900 will be worth less in April 2021. I get what you're saying about being aware of the tax implications, but I am not "missing the forest for the trees" in your comment. I have a full time job, I'm not a pro poker player, and my earnings are taxed. When tax season rolls around my refund will be reduced by the amount of the tax or I'll pay what I owe then.

Comment: @ScottSkiles No no, the forest/trees comment was specifically for Logarr who focused less on the fact that taxes might be due and more on the fact that a casino might withhold it on you. If you fully understand the tax implications then by all means, take that money, put it away to make yourself some interest and pay it to the tax man when you need to.

Comment: You can also just ask the casino to give you a check instead of the cash. They are typically happy to accommodate players this way and are used to handling large amounts of cash.

Comment: @TTT The flat rate thing is not a tax, it's withholding. Gambling winnings for non-professionals are taxed as ordinary income (and there are a number of very weird restrictions on how you can uses losses to offset winnings) and also subject to withholding under some circumstances at a flat rate. See [here](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc419) for more.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thx for that. I actually thought that was true (since I could have sworn it flowed through when I had a w2g years ago), until I read a comment above saying it was a flat rate tax, and then I looked it up and one of the top search results was a site which incorrectly stated it was a flat tax, which confirmed the comment. But I do see on 1040 Schedule 1, line 8 just flows right into all other income. (I corrected that comment, now below.)

Comment: @eps (Corrected comment) this is nitpicking, but I think if you're a professional gambler your winnings are taxed as regular income (like you said), and you can deduct losses (like you said), and also gambling related expenses. If you're not a pro gambler, winnings are still taxed as regular income, and you can still deduct gambling losses (but only if you itemize), but, unlike a pro gambler you cannot deduct gambling related expenses.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Ummm, no they aren't. Casinos need to get rid of the cash that was brought into them so they aren't used for money laundering.

Comment: Most banks don't accept significant amounts of cash unless they are familiar with the customer's cash business. Paperwork from the casino could help. In fact at certain odds levels of payouts, casinos are required to withhold tax and provide paperwork.

Comment: @corsiKa I was a casino cashier for several years. Yes, if the amount is over $10K we had to fill out federal paperwork, but we always accommodated the player.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Odd, in my area (Alberta, Canada) casinos legally aren't even allowed to do that no matter how much they win. They can only wire back an amount equal to how much was wired, the rest of the winnings must be in cash. Your local area must not be worried about money laundering.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The cheapest solution is to find a different bank or credit union. Most accept cash deposits unless they are online only and even then some offer ATM deposits.

Make sure to research fees, but there are plenty of free checking/savings accounts at banks and credit unions that will take cash deposits with no cost to you.

I switched to online banking years ago but keep a local credit union account open as a go-between for any cash transactions.

Comment: *with no cost to you* **provided that you keep a minimum balance**. - If that's a false statement I'd like to know the name of the bank, please.

Comment: @Mazura Many credit unions don't call it a minimum balance but have a separate membership account that you put something like $25/50 in and keep it there until you close your account. Some banks don't have a minimum balance requirement but waive fees if you have direct deposits hitting the account. Haven't shopped banks in a while, so not sure if any brick and mortar ones have completely free checking accounts with no minimum or other requirements.

Comment: @Mazura Chase...

Comment: [Not quite](https://accounts.chase.com/consumer/banking/online?px=WV49729&sitelink=chkacq&jp_cmp=rb/Retail_Brand_Exact_Chk-Bnk_SEM_IFP_DeskTab_Standard_NA/sea/p39987007859/chase+account&opti_ca=674189493&opti_ag=63263255183&opti_ad=409808470957&opti_key=kwd-313664483698&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgO7VgaK_5wIVGv_jBx3h-QNhEAAYASACEgJLC_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&crtv=SAQ1200). Checking: Direct deposit totaling $500 or $1,500 balance. Savings: $300 balance, or $25 or more in total Autosave or other repeating automatic transfers. - I should've said no min balance and no other BS....

Comment: @Mazura [Capital One 360](https://www.capitalone.com/bank/open-an-account/)

Comment: @HartCO FirstTech FCU has only a $5 deposit requirement - and you can make free cash deposits at any of their first-party ATMs or partner-bank/network-bank ATMs that accept cash deposits. But yeah, most banks in the US are atrocious.

Comment: @DavidK - "Prohibited Payments" ? *Say what?* Half of those are things I buy. This goes under, 'other [stuff].' - "Make sure to research fees" ... and whether or not they'll let you buy things with your money that are legal to purchase.

Comment: @Mazura The only thing I see in there that might be problematic is payments outside the US, but it's a US company, so that's no surprise. The rest seem pretty standard in terms of making sure the bank isn't liable for any potentially illegal transactions. Besides, you just use a credit card for anything "prohibited" (or anything, really), and then use the bank to pay off the card.

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations on your win. One of the skills that is often overlooked in poker is cash management.  Hopefully big tournament wills will be more common place and you need to have  plan on how to deal with the cash.  Some will be needed to replenish or build your bankroll.  How do you store that cash?  A decent safe in the house is a good idea, a safety deposit box at the bank, or some have cash boxes at the casino.  It all depends on the level you plan and how much you feel comfortable carrying around and having in the house.

While Charles Schwab is a bank, it is not a traditional one.  They started out as a brokerage account and probably started as a "cash management" business that is sort of like a bank, but with less regulatory requirements.  In order to deposit cash, you probably need a more traditional brick and mortar type bank like Chase, Wells Fargo, or a local credit union.  One of these more traditional banks would have safety deposit boxes where Charles Schwab does not seem to.

One alternative is payday lenders.  Amscot, and some of their competitors, offer free money orders.  From their website they offer unlimited money orders 365 days per year, 24 hours per day.  Crazy, huh?  Typically I would be loathe to suggest a payday lender to anyone but in this case it makes sense.  Please don't use their other services though.  Clearly this is a loss leader for them, aimed at driving traffic to their stores, that will lead to highly profitable transactions.  Again, please avoid those.

Answer (score 1):

If you regularly make payments to somebody else by a noncash method, but they'll accept cash, substitute this cash for your usual payment. For example, I normally donate to my church by instructing them online to withdraw my donation from my checking account, but in the past when I've had a large amount of cash I've simply donated the cash to them instead, and stopped making donations from my checking account until the amount I would otherwise have donated equals the cash, i.e. until I have "used up" the cash donation.

Comment: This rather depends on what the OP considers "large".  I might donate a few hundred dollars, or even a few thousand, to some charity, or otherwise make cash payments, but to me "large" would mean something in the neighborhood of my annual income.

Comment: Also, the question said "quickly". It could take a while to "deposit" enough cash by paying people with it. Otherwise, I like the idea.